# ¿Como puedo integrar la api de google drive para php en un hosting web?

Tags: php, api, hosting, drive

he estado desarrollando una pequeña app para poder administrar archivos en drive mediante php
funciona todo ok en local, pero al momento de querer usarla en un host web es un dolor de cabeza ya que he tratado de subir todos los archivos de la api y son mas de 25000 lo que provoca errores al quererla subir, quisiera saber si hay otro metodo de incluirla en el archivo php y poderla subir al host. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de incluir la API de Google Drive en tu aplicación PHP en un hosting web:

1. Utilizar una biblioteca cliente PHP para la API de Google Drive: Hay varias bibliotecas cliente disponibles, como Google API Client Library for PHP, que simplifican la implementación de la API de Google Drive en tu aplicación PHP. Con esta biblioteca, puedes incluir solo los archivos necesarios para tu aplicación, lo que reduce el tamaño de los archivos que debes subir a tu hosting web.
2. Usar Composer para incluir la API de Google Drive en tu aplicación: Composer es un gestor de paquetes para PHP que te permite descargar e incluir bibliotecas en tu proyecto de manera sencilla. Puedes utilizar Composer para descargar la biblioteca cliente de la API de Google Drive y agregarla a tu aplicación, lo que te permitirá incluir solo los archivos necesarios para tu aplicación.

> Agrega la siguiente línea a tu archivo composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
}
```

> Ejecuta el siguiente comando para instalar la API de Google Drive:

```
composer install
```

> Finalmente, incluye la siguiente línea al inicio de tu archivo PHP para cargar la API de Google Drive:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

> Después de estos pasos, puedes comenzar a utilizar la API de Google Drive en tu proyecto PHP. Para ello, debes tener una cuenta de Google y haber creado un proyecto en la Consola de Google Cloud para obtener las credenciales necesarias para autenticarte y utilizar la API.